# PC register shows value above the last instruction number

Tags: c, assembly, pic

I m new to CCS C Programming, and I was doing an exercise on my book. I copied the exact same code from my book to the compiler, but the program didnt work. I did some examination on the registers and and the instructions, and found this at the end of the code:

```
.................... enable_interrupts(0X0BC0); 
00A4:  MOVLW  C0
00A5:  IORWF  0B,F
....................  
....................  
.................... } 
....................  
00A6:  SLEEP
```

But the register on Proteus says:

```
PC: $00A7
INSTR.:ADDLW 0x1FF
```

And there was no instruction like that on the output file. What is happening here?

Comment: What was the goal of this program? Enabling SLEEP and waking up the PIC with external interrupt, interrupt-on-change????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash memory cannot be really "empty" but it is either 0x0000, 0xFFFF (or unreadable if it has ECC bits - what the PIC16 does not have).

Obviously on PIC16 "empty" Flash contains the value 0xFFFF.

The instruction "ADDLW 0x1FF" is represented by this number so the CPU will interpret "empty" Flash memory as if it was filled with the instruction "ADDLW 0x1FF".

As far as I know the SLEEP instruction stops the CPU at the next instruction (this is "ADDLW 0x1FF") and then waits until some interrupt event occurs.